# Figure section including image goes above the section definition

Tags: floats, positioning

Trying to use the following code:

```
\subsection {Shop}

\begin{figure}
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{shop.png}
    }
    \caption{Shop Tab}
\label{fig:shopTab}
\end{figure}
```

The image supposed to go after the section in the PDF file created, something like:

1. Shop

image

But it goes above the Shop section.
What is the problem here?

I am using that kind of figure construction (with makebox) because otherwise image is too small or doesn't fit the page (because of shift to the right, it is not aligned to the left).